# Issue with saving UITextfield information

Tags: objective-c, sdk, nsmutablearray

I'm having issues(crashes) when I try to save UITextFields information with NSUserdefaults. I know it has something to do with the array that I'm using. Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)generateNumbers 
{
    // release and remove everyting from the name array
    //    [nameArray release];
    nameArray = nil;

    // reinitilize the name array
    nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Loop through the textfields to get the names into the nameArray
    for (int textFieldCount = 0; textFieldCount<[textFieldArray count]; textFieldCount++) {
        [nameArray addObject:[[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:textFieldCount] text]];
    }

    // Randomly sort the names in the array
    [nameArray sortUsingFunction:randomSort context:nil];

    // Add the random names back into the text fields
    for (int textFieldCount = 0; textFieldCount<[textFieldArray count]; textFieldCount++) {
        [[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:textFieldCount] setText:[nameArray     objectAtIndex:textFieldCount]];
    }
}

      int randomSort(id obj1, id obj2, void *context ) {
         // returns random number -1 0 1
       return (arc4random()%3 - 1);
}
```

---

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
          [super viewWillAppear:animated];
          [tex1 setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]         objectForKey:@"storedTextValue48"]];
```

---

```
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tex1.text forKey:@"storedTextValue48"];
```

Comment: Please fix the code. It won't even compile

Comment: What kind of crash error?  where is text1 being declared?  Are you using ARC?

Comment: Things work just fine until I added the NSUserdefaults to save information. Here is the error message that I'm receiving: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to use [synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) method when you are saving data:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```